# Print preview on Chrome changing styles of the page

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I'm using Chrome 92.0.4515.107.

When I click on the print button, the print preview pops up, but the website loses its styles.

But after I click and the print preview pops up, the styles are lost.

This doesn't happen when I use Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" />`

This links a stylesheet to style the printed page.

You could also try a print media query to do the same effect:

`@media print { }`